# unable to subscribe to router in a container component - Angular2 routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Currently I have:

```
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';

@Component({...})

export class Index {
  constructor(public router: Router) {
    this.router.subscribe({...});
  }
}
```

There are other functions in this component, but they are not relevant to the problem

I have tried putting debuggers and console.log() in the subscribe function but no matter what I do I cannot get anything to happen. I've also tried moving the router.subscribe() to ngOnInit() with the same result. Nothing.

I need to be able to switch resources from 'accounts' to 'users' or others, and make appropriate API calls, based on the state of the URL. Currently I do not see why this shouldn't work. Is there something obvious I am missing? Are there restrictions on subscribing to the router more than once? I am already doing it in another component and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
this.router.root.subscribe({...});
```

to get all route navigation events.

Comment: This works, thanks! However, It brings up a small issue. Now I am subscribing to the router every single time there is a change, not just when I am changing the path within one section of the site.

Comment: You can try `this.router.parent.subscribe()` but that's a bit brittle because the component depends on the level of nesting. The router is subject to bigger changes anyway. If it works for you I would go for it and revisit when the updated router is available.

Comment: The parent router of my component is the root router, so that doesn't help much. Are you aware of any way to make a subscription to the root router available in other components? I want to avoid subscribing to the router more than once

Comment: You can inject the router to a service that forwards router events. Why don't you want to subscribe more than once?

Comment: I was told that it is not in best interest to subscribe to the same observable in many places. It seems redundant. But if there isn't a more elegant solution, I might have to